# How to find difference for two time values in string?

Tags: c#

I am working on a new project in c#, i have no experience with date and time.

Here i need to find the difference between two time values which is in string format

```
string pointavalue = comboBox1.Text + ":" + comboBox2.Text + ":" + comboBox5.Text;
string pointbvalue = comboBox3.Text + ":" + comboBox4.Text + ":" + comboBox6.Text;
string pointcvalue = comboBox7.Text + ":" + comboBox8.Text + ":" + comboBox9.Text;
DateTime pointa = DateTime.Parse(pointavalue, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
DateTime pointb = DateTime.Parse(pointbvalue, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
DateTime pointc = DateTime.Parse(pointcvalue, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
string time1 = pointa.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
string time2 = pointb.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
string time3 = pointc.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

There is three Values pointavalue, pointbvalue. pointcvalue.
They are combined string values of comboboxes.

Now  how do i subtract pointbvalues from pointavalues?
I know they are in string format so operations cannot be performed.

the code you are looking is not mine, someone helped me but its working as a expected.

I am learning C# so bear with me.

ok i think figure out something, but still i can't solve it.

Here is my recent work with the code

```
DateTime inputa = DateTime.Parse(label21.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        DateTime inputb = DateTime.Parse(label23.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
if (pointa < pointb)
        {
            TimeSpan diff1 = pointb.Subtract(pointa);
            DateTime d1=Convert.ToDateTime(diff1);
            if (d1 < inputa)
            {
                label34.Text = "fail";
            }
            else
            {
                label34.Text = "pass";
            }
```

Here i want to check the condition of the time diff1 and inputa, that's it that's all i need to finish this project.

Comment: You are expected to be doing basic research before asking questions on SO.  Just doing a simple search on how to subtract dates would give you your result, as would simply looking up the documentation for the types that you're working with.

Comment: If you are strictly working with time of day the closest data type in .Net is `TimeSpan` though it will allow both negative values and values higher than 24 hours, so you have to do your own bounds checking.  If you have a date as well then start with `DateTime` which will give `TimeSpan` when you subtract them from each other.

Comment: @juharr My concept is simple, i need to subtract two time values Say: 23:00:00 and 01:00:00, which should give the answer 2 hours not -22. that's why i asked this question, i am not an expert in these area. if you still don't understand what i am trying to achieve please point out where you lost me...

Comment: @Navisgero Why would the difference between 23:00 and 01:00 be 2 instead of 22 (the negative depends on the order, but clearly the magnitude of the difference is 22)?  Unless you mean that 23:00 is on one day and 01:00 is on the next, in which case why don't you have the date included?

Comment: @juharr that's why come to you... i don't know how to do this... if it is not much of a trouble, can you help me? this one step blocks me to complete my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you can't solve this problem is that you are trying to compare two different data types, Timespan and Datetime are not same

- Either convert all your string to "Timespan" (That is  better option).
- Datetime will give you the present date, but it seems you don't need that.
- Last but not least learn some basics before you ask these questions.

Answer (score 1):

One more simple example:

```
void Main()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime yesterday = now.AddDays(-1);
    TimeSpan difference = yesterday - now;
    Console.WriteLine (difference.GetType().Name);
    Console.WriteLine (difference.TotalSeconds); // expecting -86400
}
```

running this will print

```
TimeSpan
-86400
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [DateTime.Substract method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
TimeSpan abdiff = pointb.Substract(pointa);
TimeSpan bcdiff = pointc.Substract(pointb);
```

Alternatively, you can use the - operator, you get back a Timespan which contains the differences:

```
TimeSpan abdiff = pointb - pointa;
TimeSpan bcdiff = pointc - pointb;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your combo boxes contain the hour, minute, and second then you could do the following.

```
TimeSpan pointa = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(comboBox1.Text), int.Parse(comboBox2.Text), int.Parse(comboBox5.Text));
TimeSpan pointb = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(comboBox3.Text), int.Parse(comboBox4.Text), int.Parse(comboBox6.Text));
TimeSpan pointc = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(comboBox7.Text), int.Parse(comboBox8.Text), int.Parse(comboBox9.Text));

TimeSpan aTob = pointa > pointb 
    ? pointa - pointb 
    : (pointa + TimeSpan.FromDays(1)) - pointb;
```

Basically this assumes that your combo boxes only have valid hour (0-23), minute (0-59), and second (0-59) values.  Then you just need to determine if your times are on the same day or not.  If you assume that `pointa` is latter than `pointb` then checking if it is greater than `pointb` means you can do a straight subtraction.  If not then it must be the time for the next day and you just add 1 day to it before subtracting `pointb`.

This is based on your assertion that 01:00 - 23:00 should be 2 hours and not -22.  Thought it would be best if there where a date included so you would know for sure if the times are on the same day or the next day or from completely different years.

Comment: same results, i don't  even know how to explain my situation here, can you come in teamviewer? my email is walkingtr21@gmail.com

Comment: please I have absolutely no idea in timespan and the codes in your answer points out day, which is a problem in my program.